# Symfony2: creation of an event listener: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '('

Tags: php, symfony

I've implemented the ["**How to create an Event Listener**"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) to catch & handle all exceptions throw by my app.

But, when I go to the home page, I got this errors (from the apache logs):

In production mode (app.php):

> syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '(' appProdProjectContainer.php line 383

In dev. mode (app_dev.php):

> syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '(' in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1131

I've googled, but I didn't find something that can solve my issue...

So, here, it's my *services.yml* loaded by the "DependencyInjection/lhnbackendExtension" class:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.lhn-exception:
        class: lhn\backendBundle\Listener\LhnExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

--> I've tried to configure the service in a XML file, but the same error occurs...

And the basic listener implementation:

```
namespace lhn\backendBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LhnExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event){
        // We get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();
        $message = 'My Error says: ' . $exception->getMessage();

        // Customize our response object to display our exception details
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent($message);
        $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());

        // Send our modified response object to the event
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `lhn-exception` by `lhn_exception`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go without hypen in the service name.

```
services:
    kernel.listener.lhn-exception:    
    ...
```

Becomes:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.lhn_exception:    
    ...
```